# MomentJS and function returning NaN

Tags: javascript, momentjs

The goal here is for a user to be able to add an employee with some basic info about that employee to a database and the program prints the list of employees to the HTML in a table. I also need to calculate the total wages paid to the employee since they started working. I'm not supposed to save the difference of time saved in the database but to calculate it on each database pull/push.

I'm using firebase as my database.

I have a calculateMonthsWorked function. MonthsWorked is a global variable initialized to 0.

```
 function calculateMonthsWorked() {
        startDate = (moment(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY").format("MM/DD/YYYY"))
        monthsWorked = (moment().diff(moment(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY"), "months"))
        console.log("months worked is " + monthsWorked + " and the type is " + typeof monthsWorked)
}
```

I call this function to test whether or not it works at the end of my click event. It seems to calculate it properly.

```
$('#submitBTN').on('click', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        // get values of user inputs
        var name = $('#name').val().trim();
        var role = $('#role').val().trim()
        startDate = $('#startDate').val().trim()
        monthlyRate = $('#monthlyRate').val().trim();
        // clear values
        $('#name').val("");
        $('#role').val("");
        $('#startDate').val("");
        $('#monthlyRate').val("");
        databaseRef.push({
            name: name,
            role: role,
            startDate: startDate,
            monthlyRate: monthlyRate
        });
        calculateMonthsWorked()
    })
```

When I'm grabbing the data from the database to print to the table upon a reload, I call the calculateMonthsWorked function in here.

```
databaseRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
        var newEmployee = snapshot.val();
        calculateMonthsWorked()
        $('#employeeTable').append("<tr><td>" + newEmployee.name + "</td><td>" + newEmployee.role + "</td><td>" + newEmployee.startDate + "</td><td>" + monthsWorked + "</td><td>$" + newEmployee.monthlyRate + "</td><td></td></tr>");
    });
```

But doing this changes everything to NaN and now it says it's no longer a number in the console.

[image]

The full script for those who wish to see it all in order.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyDcNRNdiPbOezI3PsGPQ-kS9u79G8eaYoU",
        authDomain: "database-practice-bda3.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://database-practice-bda3.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "database-practice-bda3",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "498652093118"
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var monthsWorked = 0;
    var totalBilled = 0;
    var startDate = null;
    var monthlyRate = 0;



    function calculateMonthsWorked() {
        startDate = (moment(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY").format("MM/DD/YYYY"))
        monthsWorked = (moment().diff(moment(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY"), "months"))
        console.log("months worked is " + monthsWorked + " and the type is " + typeof monthsWorked)
    }

    // function calculateTotalBilled(){
    //     totalBilled = monthsWorked * monthlyRate;
    // }

    databaseRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
        var newEmployee = snapshot.val();
        calculateMonthsWorked()
        $('#employeeTable').append("<tr><td>" + newEmployee.name + "</td><td>" + newEmployee.role + "</td><td>" + newEmployee.startDate + "</td><td>" + monthsWorked + "</td><td>$" + newEmployee.monthlyRate + "</td><td></td></tr>");
    });


    $('#submitBTN').on('click', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        // get values of user inputs
        var name = $('#name').val().trim();
        var role = $('#role').val().trim()
        startDate = $('#startDate').val().trim()
        monthlyRate = $('#monthlyRate').val().trim();

        // clear values
        $('#name').val("");
        $('#role').val("");
        $('#startDate').val("");
        $('#monthlyRate').val("");

        databaseRef.push({
            name: name,
            role: role,
            startDate: startDate,
            monthlyRate: monthlyRate
        });

        calculateMonthsWorked()
    })

});
```

Comment: You are parsing a date, then formatting it to a string, then parsing it again: `startDate = (moment(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY").format("MM/DD/YYYY")); monthsWorked = (moment().diff(moment(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY"), "months"))`. Seems like what you'd want to do is `startDate = moment(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY"); monthsWorked = (moment().diff(startDate, "months"))` You should also return something from a function rather than setting global variables.

Comment: Unfortunately, swapping your code for mine still produces NaN on the HTML.

Comment: Well, that's why it's a comment, not an answer :).

Comment: Since you already know how to use console, `console.log()` is your friend here. Debug the code by logging each variable you build with moment. Debugging would have been faster than posting so much info ;) Cheers!!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I ran into the same result (NaN) when accidentally calling `moment.unix()` instead of `moment().unix()`.  Hopefully that helps a future traveller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would change:

```
function calculateMonthsWorked(startDate) {
    var startDate = moment(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
    var monthsWorked = moment().diff(startDate, "months");
    console.log("months worked is " + monthsWorked + " and the type is " + typeof monthsWorked);
    return monthsWorked;
}
```

The above code will remove the double parse, and return the number of months to its caller. Later:

```
databaseRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
    var newEmployee = snapshot.val();
    var monthsWorked = calculateMonthsWorked(newEmployee.startDate);
    $('#employeeTable').append("<tr><td>" + newEmployee.name + "</td><td>" + newEmployee.role + "</td><td>" + newEmployee.startDate + "</td><td>" + monthsWorked + "</td><td>$" + newEmployee.monthlyRate + "</td><td></td></tr>");
});
```

Note that here, we're passing the start date from `newEmployee` to the function. There was nothing connecting `startDate` (the variable) to `newEmployee.startDate` (the property) previously.

Remove the declaration of `monthsWorked` and `startDate` from above.

You might want to consider moving the code that sets the HTML out of the `databaseRef.on` function into its own, so that you can call it elsewhere (like in your onclick handler).